# Gulp Error: Cannot find module 'jshint/src/cli'

Tags: javascript, terminal, gulp, jshint

So I've got a fresh install of El Capitan and I'm giving these task runners another go.

I'm following [sitepoint's An introduction to Gulp.js](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/), but I'm stuck on step four, when I try to run `gulp jshint` I get "`Error: Cannot find module 'jshint/src/cli'`"

I've no idea what's causing this, which is why I'm asking here. Below are a couple of screen grabs to help with the issue.

[image: Terminal error when running gulp jshint]

[image: Folder structer for gulp project]

As always, I'm eternally grateful for any advice.

Comment: Is jshint installed?

Comment: Yes, it is. I even reinstalled it to be sure and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: How did you installed it? Needs to be installed like this: `npm install jshint gulp-jshint --save-dev` from the root of your node app.

Comment: I used `npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev` as stated in step four of the tutorial I originally linked to. It would have been within the test folder directory, I assume this is where it should be installed, yes?

Comment: delete folder `gulp-jshint` try reinstall.

Comment: @lateralaus did you also do `npm install jshint`?

Comment: I used `npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev` is that different to `npm install jshint`?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

You need to install [jshint](http://jshint.com/install/) as well, that will sort out the issue.

```
> npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint
```

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. I think the developers made a change to the structure of gulp-jshint in the latest version which has caused this problem (if you see https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint/issues/131). I noticed a peer dependency warning when I installed `gulp-jshint`.

Comment: when typing  npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint  it works fine with me

Answer (score 27):

It turns out I need to use `npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint` instead of `npm install gulp-jshint --save-dev` as the tutorial stated. Discussion around this was found at https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint/issues/131 with massive thanks to @user3042437 for suppling the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get the error after you put in the correct syntax above,
(npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint), which works.

Before you run the install again, go into your package.json file and remove the lines for jshint and gulp-jshint before you run the install, make sure you edit you package.json to remove the lines that call jshint and gulp-jshint, otherwise, the error will persist.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the order of the phrasing does matter. I found out that this 
`npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint` does not work but this `npm install jshint gulp-jshint --save` works

Answer (score -1):

Here you target `jshint`, which you probably didn't install. (You do this in `gulp.task('jshint', function() {`.)

Try this:

```
gulp.task('gulp-jshint', function() {
```

This matches the way you `require`d it.

```
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a temporary solution for bypassing this error. Even this temporary solution will also work properly, if in case you don't want to use jshint.js file in you application anywhere.

1. Go to your gulpfile.js file.
2. Comment the code in line number 4.

   ```
   var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
   ```
3. Now, run gulp command in your terminal. Your server will be up.

Comment: This answer does not fix the root problem, which I think should be the focus of an answer on SO.