# How to fix: npm error 'cannot find gulp-cli module' when running gulp, despite gulp-cli being installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I am following [this SASS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sk5jMurFHCo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jxJX7vojNVK-o8ubDZEcNb&index=2) by net-ninja on YouTube which recommends installing gulp with SASS.  However I can't get gulp to work.  As per the tutorial I created the gulpfile.js, index.html and index.css then I ran the following npm commands:

```
npm init
npm install gulp gulp-sass sass --save-dev
```

When I ran gulp, I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-cli'

So I ran

```
npm install gulp-cli --save-dev
```

But the error persists.  As per the comments in the YouTube tutorial I also installed gulp and gulp-cli as global modules with:

```
npm install --global gulp gulp-cli --save-dev
```

but this did not change anything. Gulp-cli is in both my global modules folder and the node_modules folder within the project folder. Can anyone propose a solution please?

Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406738/cant-get-gulp-to-run-cannot-find-module-gulp-util) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984558/gulp-error-cannot-find-module-jshint-src-cli), but not exact and following both of them doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you run the commands from the project root / where the gulpfile is?

Comment: Yes, using the terminal in VScode

Answer (score 3):

In my case -force did it

```
npm install --global gulp-cli -force
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, on other installations (WSL2 ubuntu 20.04) it worked with no problems, this time around it did not (on dedicated ubuntu 20.04 dev server).

Anyway, followed the gulp get started [Gulp website](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start)
While I was in the root directory and after running
`npm install --global gulp-cli`
everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with the installation and then I had to go to the official [gulp documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/) . What I noticed was that;

1. running `gulp` and getting `Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-cli'` was becuase gulp-cli wasn't previously installed on my local machine.
2. When you try to install gulp-cli after this error message, it still doesn't sync and you keep getting gulp-cli module not found.

To fix this:

1. I had to trace all the gulp folders in my installation directory in ubuntu I found them by running `which gulp` on my terminal
2. I deleted all of those files, so that when I run `which gulp` it wouldn't find any installation of gulp
3. Next, I followed the installation steps described in the gulp official documentation - https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/
4. Now when I ran `npm install --save-dev gulp` in my project directory and started gulp by running `gulp`, the issues where fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `yarn` to install `gulp` instead:

```bash
sudo yarn add gulp --location=global
```